# O que usar para conectar à Web Api de acesso somente interno

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api

Sou iniciante e construí uma aplicação Mobile em C# que conecta à um Web Api. Porém, o Web Api ficará em um servidor que tem acesso somente interno, o que teoricamente protegeria o BD.
Como fazer para a minha aplicação (pública) ter acesso à esse Web Api que só permite acesso interno ?
Crio outro Web Api com acesso externo que chamará esse Web Api ? Um Proxy ?
Se puderem indicar algum material ou exemplo, agradeço.

Comment: Tem um ótimo artigo que resolve seu problema aqui. [Artigo](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/)

Answer (score 1):

Essa questão é bem opinativa e depende do seu cenário específico.

Vou tentar enumerar alguns cenários que talvez possam se parecer com o seu, mas ai depende de você qual é o melhor:

- se for impossível tornar pública a Web API que hoje é restrita, e também for impossível acessar o banco de dados por fora dessa API então só tem um jeito, fazer um Proxy e implementar na API restrita tudo o que for necessário
- se for possível acessar o banco de dados por fora dessa API, então talvez seja melhor usar algumas funções da API restrita quando possível, e quando necessário acessar diretamente o banco, isso se for realmente necessário... ou então usar a primeira alternativa para não quebrar o encapsulamento, caso isso seja uma premissa do sistema.
- se a API restrita puder ser publicada, é possível usar algum tipo de autenticação, em que o utilizador passa uma chave `appKey` que poderia ser usada juntamente com o referrer caso seja uma API para ser usada diretamente do browser (tipo, se o referrer não for o domínio registrado para aquela `appKey` então o acesso é negado). Assim sendo seria necessário que o cliente (utilizador) registrasse a app dentro do seu sistema